# Understanding Gtk template objects

Tags: c, templates, gtk, gtk3

While looking at the code for gnome-builder which is written in C using Gtk and other libraries, I found the following code for a shortcut window definition:

ide-shortcuts-window-private.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define IDE_TYPE_SHORTCUTS_WINDOW (ide_shortcuts_window_get_type())

G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (IdeShortcutsWindow, ide_shortcuts_window, IDE, SHORTCUTS_WINDOW, GtkShortcutsWindow)

G_END_DECLS
```

ide-shortcuts-window.c:

```
#define G_LOG_DOMAIN "ide-shortcuts-window"
#include "config.h"

#include <glib/gi18n.h>

#include "ide-shortcuts-window-private.h"

struct _IdeShortcutsWindow
{
  GtkShortcutsWindow parent_instance;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (IdeShortcutsWindow, ide_shortcuts_window, GTK_TYPE_SHORTCUTS_WINDOW)

static void
ide_shortcuts_window_class_init (IdeShortcutsWindowClass *klass)
{
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass);

  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (widget_class, "/org/gnome/libide-gui/ui/ide-shortcuts-window.ui");
}

static void
ide_shortcuts_window_init (IdeShortcutsWindow *self)
{
  gtk_widget_init_template (GTK_WIDGET (self));
}
```

And this ui file which describes the window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.19 -->
  <template class="IdeShortcutsWindow">
    <property name="modal">true</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkShortcutsSection">
        <property name="visible">true</property>
        <property name="section-name">editor</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes" context="shortcut window">Editor Shortcuts</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkShortcutsGroup">
            <property name="visible">true</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes" context="shortcut window">General</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkShortcutsShortcut">
                <property name="visible">true</property>
                <property name="title" translatable="yes" context="shortcut window">Show help</property>
                <property name="accelerator">F1</property>
              </object>
            </child>
              ...............
```

I have built some Gtk applications before but I have never seen or used such a way of describing objects and I am having a hard time understanding this code. I know that the .ui file describes a template from which the structure IdeShortcutsWindow will be initialized. But I don't quite understand how to use it. Should I create an instance of the structure like so:

```
IdeShortcutsWindow shortcuts;
```

But then how do I initialize it? Should I call the functions defined in ide-shortcuts-window.c for the instance? While looking at the rest of the code I didn't find a single other place where an instance of `IdeShortcutsWindow` is used.

Comment: By use I mean how can I create an instance of IdeShortcutsWindow and show it with gtk_window_present() for example.

Comment: You will need [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html)

Comment: Should I associate a GtkBuilder object with the ui file and call gtk_builder_get_object()? But what ID should I pass to gtk_builder_get_object()?

Comment: No, you use `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child`. `member_name` should be in `Private`-section. Go to `Building composite widgets from template XML` [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget.description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create an instance of the structure like so:
> `IdeShortcutsWindow shortcuts;`

A new instance of the class is created with `g_object_new (IDE_TYPE_SHORTCUTS_WINDOW, NULL)`. You can see the same in [gnome-builder code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-builder/-/blob/master/src/libide/gui/ide-application-actions.c#L288).

Sometimes helper functions are provided to create new instances.  Say for example: `gtk_button_new ()` and `g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_BUTTON, NULL)` are [the same](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-24/gtk/gtkbutton.c#L1235).  This is applicable to all `GObject`s and not specific to `GtkBuilder` templates.

See related documentations: [1](https://developer.gnome.org/SubclassGObject/) [2](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html)

Please note that `some_type_new()` is a function that can be used only in C. Languages using [GObject introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io) bindings (eg: Python) shall only use `g_object_new (...)` to create new objects.

Personally I maintain a template project to help me easily develop GTK Applications, may be helpful for you: [Link](https://gitlab.com/sadiq/my-gtemplate/)